# Store array in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database, store

I was trying store an array into JSON. For the JSON script, is it correct to write it just like this?
{"bgArr" : ["bg1","bg2","bg3"]}

Might need some correction. I doing this to make the splice function to be fully work.

```js
var promoCode = '';
var bg1 = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/01/22/23/eye-5248678__340.jpg';
var bg2 = 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg';
var bg3 = 'http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/41500000/adorable-puppies-cute-puppies-41538743-590-393.jpg';

var JsonObject, bgArr;

// JS array
var bgArr = [bg1, bg2, bg3];

// Convert (js array) to (json object)
JsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bgArr));

// type
console.log(typeof(JsonObject));

// JsonObject
console.log(JsonObject);


for(var i = bgArr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  selectBG = bgArr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*bgArr.length), 1)[0];
  console.log(selectBG);
}



if (selectBG === bg1) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg2) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg3) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH600';
 
} else if (bgArr.length === 0) {
  alert("No more voucher, back to main website");
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
}
```

Comment: It's a valid way of doing it - I'm just not sure it's necessarily going to be the most helpful way of doing it, in terms of referencing it later on in your code

Comment: So overall it will work?

Comment: _"Convert (js array) to (json object)"_ - no, that converts a JS array to JSON (a string) and then back into a JS array. It doesn't convert it to an object. `typeof []` is always object.

Comment: So how should I write it? Pretty confuse about it.

Comment: var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);                                                                                 Just discover this, will this be better for storing array in json?

Comment: That is the only way to store the array as JSON, since JSON is a string. When you parse it again it is no longer JSON, but a javascript object. (It is very unclear what you are trying to do).

Comment: I was trying to test the splice function where the array will empty after 3 attempt, so I think storing the array in JSON would help

Comment: The array empty function never work unless I set it to loop automatically 3 times.